# Is there a tool to measure the "maturity" (age) of a code in Git?

Tags: code-quality, git, static-analysis

The [`vc-annotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15460551/450148) in Emacs is a nice tool to see the "maturity" (age) of each line of code in colors. More blue dark, more mature, more red, less mature. This functionality has already been considered to be implemented in MediaWiki (but I don't know if it ever came to be). Usually, in a active project, untouchables lines or functions are very stable (it's applicable to Wiki too - information not disputed tend to be better) and bug-free.

Is there a tool to make a analysis of maturity of a code on Git based on the age of each line? That output something like:

```
Total lines: 500
Until 1 month lines: 100
1mo-6mo lines: 200
6mo-1yr lines: 100
more than 1yr lines: 100
```

This could be very useful in active projects (in abandoned maybe it is useless since the entire code would be false-flagged to "mature").

Comment: Hello Felipe, welcome to SO :) As answered below by O.F., SonarQube has this feature. I did use something similar but the use of this feature made the syntactic colorization quite unreadable, so the leaddev did modify background colors with dark gray scales instead of text colors.

Comment: I think a better word may be "age".    Also does changing the indentation level of a snippet reset this counter?  This could happen if something was put inside a conditional without changing the code itself.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you can use: https://github.com/erikbern/git-of-theseus

It can visualize the amount of code still in use since its conception.

This is a graph of the Git codebase itself:

[image]

Comment: Funny. It hints at a soft ceiling for the amount of LOC in use.

Comment: @Mindwin to go beyond that border is the land of enterprise code Simba. You must never venture there.

Answer (score 12):

On browsing through the 
 of @Niels van Reijmersdal [answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/40785/41487), I found this written in the README

> [Markovtsev Vadim](https://twitter.com/tmarkhor) implemented a very similar analysis that claims to be 20%-6x faster than Git of Theseus. It's named [Hercules](https://github.com/src-d/hercules) and there's a great [blog post](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/hercules/) about all the complexity going into the analysis of Git history.

So well lookup [Hercules](https://github.com/src-d/hercules) and go through the [blog post](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/hercules/).

Disclaimer: I have neither used [Hercules](https://github.com/src-d/hercules), nor
[git-of-theseus](https://github.com/erikbern/git-of-theseus).

Answer (score 11):

Well, [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) has a metric actually called `Maturity`, so, yeah. :)

Answer (score 2):

The best tool I know is Codescene https://codescene.io.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/). This will give some insight about code.